# Why the program execution ends at the first iteration of for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

C++ Program To Generate Random Password

As stated in the code(as comment), the program execution doesn't end or works fine without those lines of code but with them, the program ends without executing the next iteration and lines of code that follow.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

float random(){
  long int t = static_cast<long int> (time(NULL));
  float randNum = fmod(t*3.141592653589793238 , 1);
  return randNum;
}

void generateCharacters(char choice[],char *p){
  float r=random()*(strlen(choice)+1);
  *p = choice[int(r)];
}


int main(){
  char password[] = "";
  char characters[] = "";
  char *p;
  char numbers[] = "0123456789";
  char smallLetters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  char capitalLetters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  char symbols[] = "`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:'.,><?/";
  int length=6,i;

  for(i=0;i<length;i++){

    //line of code that's stopping the loop
    generateCharacters(numbers,p);
    p[1]='\0';
    strcat(characters,p);

    generateCharacters(smallLetters,p);
    p[1]='\0';
    strcat(characters,p);

    generateCharacters(capitalLetters,p);
    p[1]='\0';
    strcat(characters,p);

    generateCharacters(symbols,p);
    p[1]='\0';
    strcat(characters,p);
    
    password[i] = characters[int(random()*length)];
    //upper lines of code is causing loop termination

    cout<<endl<<"Program Execution stops here! Loop terminates!";
  }

  cout<<endl<<"This line doesn't execute!";
  password[length]='\0';
  cout<<endl<<"Password = "<<password;
}
```

Comment: If you google _how to debug a program_ you'll probably find what you need.

Comment: "the program execution doesn't end" And that is desired behaviour?

Comment: @Enlico Telling question authors to google something is not considered politely helpful. At least refer them to a nice introduction, like https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should be using `std::string` instead of `char *` and C-style strings.  If you did that, more than likely you would not have had the issue you're seeing now.

Comment: Also, the program to generate a random password could have been done by using one single string of all the possible characters, and then using `<random>` and a [std::uniform_int_distribution(0, length_of_character_string)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), concatenate the character onto a string in a loop.  The way you have it now is not as random as it could be, as you always pick a number, then a small letter, than a capital letter, then a symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line of code in question `p` is used uninitialised and gets write-dereferenced inside the called function.
That should give you at least two causes for undefined behaviour, which means absolutely anything can happen.
With that, all bets are off, end of explanation for the line in question.

If you get no problems for the line after the one in focus, i.e. for `p[1]='\0';` then you are just lucky, or unlucky, depending on your approach. It is also write dereferencing the still uninitialised pointer and even beyond.